# How to fill Oxyplot AreaSeries in different areas?

Tags: wpf, charts, series, oxyplot

I would like to create a `AreaSeries` series in `Oxyplot` that consists of a set of intervals.

See picture of what I would like to achieve:
[AreaSeries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBRJt.png)

This is the code I use to fill in an area of the chart. The series is composed of 2 linear axis.

```
            seriesArea = new AreaSeries { Title = "2Hz" };
            for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                //Draw a vertical line from a specific value.
                //This represents the starting point of the area series.
                //eg: triggers[0]=0; triggers[1]=236 first area (see picture)

                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(triggers[0], j)); 
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                //This time the ending point of the area series.

                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(triggers[1], j));
            }
            seriesArea.Color = OxyColors.LightPink;
            seriesArea.Fill = OxyColors.LightPink;
            plotModel.Series.Add(seriesArea);
```

I cannot seem to figure out what I have to do in order to draw the same series and full only the intervals that I want. If I use the above code, the series fills up also the areas that I would like to leave blank.

I tried to use `seriesArea.Points2.Add(new DataPoint(i, j));` in places where I want it to not draw and draw the `seriesArea.Points2` transparent, but it seem to not work as I expected.

Please let me know if there is a way that I could draw different intervals in a `Oxyplot` `chart` with the `same series`.